# Contain function with double quotes

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, power-automate, flow, formula

I need to find a string which has double quotes (") in it:

```
"userId": "xyz-bdd2-06870916684f"
```

within another string to use it as condition in a filter action. The **userId** is retrieved with the O365 User action.

[image]

My filter condition looks like this:

```
@contains(string(item()?['_assignments']), concat('"userID": "', outputs('Benutzerprofil_abrufen_(V2)')?
```

I tried many variants like marking the quotes with a backslash ( \" ), passing it as string variable or remove the added backslashes. The condition returns always a *false*. If I only search for the **userId** I get some results. Yet I need to search for that string including the "userID": "xyz"

Comment: Can you mention why you want to check it ? I meant what is the purpose of it? do you want to extract User Id?

Which Graph API you are trying to call? getting Planner tasks?

Comment: Try removing space after colon (**:**) in the formula: `concat('"userID": "',`. use like this: `concat('"userID":"',`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Also, formula you provided is incomplete. few closing brackets are missing in formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a "dirty" trick to find the right string.

By adding some nested replace-functions I removed blanks, colons & double quotes to have a single, long string.

Then I filtered by

```
userIdxyz-bdd2-06870916684f
```

Filter function:

```
@contains(replace(replace(replace(string(item()?['_assignments']), ' ', ''), ':', ''), '"', ''), concat('userId', outputs('Benutzerprofil_abrufen_(V2)')?['body/id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing space after colon (:) in the formula: `concat('"userID": "'`,

Formula in below format works for me:

```
contains(string(item()?['_assignments']), concat('"userID":"', 'xyz-bdd2-06870916684f"'))
```

Replace `'xyz-bdd2-06870916684f"'` this part with your dynamic content.